# What's a suitable return type for this Java method?

Tags: java

we are implementing a system with Strategy pattern.

Some callers to a specific methods require a Hashmap of data while in some case it would be a user-defined DTO. Some need both.

How do we decide which return type to use, instead of an Arraylist containing Hashmap and DTO ? Is there anything more approporiate?

Example:

Some caller needs only 2 strings and prefers a Hashmap.

Some other caller to the same API needs 12 values which are suited to put in a DTO. 1st caller does not need all the elements in the DTO.

3rd caller needs all 14 values and hence both structures.

Comment: Please provide some more context.

Comment: In what scenario do you need both?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the different cases? Why would you need a HashMap OR a DTO? What data would be contained?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If some callers require `Map` (BTW don't use concrete types like `HashMap` in your interfaces) and others an object, there might be two reasons for that:

- the method returns completely different things depending on the arguments (e.g. *if the flag is set, return a map of privileges whereas if it's not, return object representing user himself*)
- you are returning different *view* of the same entity

In the first case your interface is seriously flawed and should be redesigned. Probably you need two methods performing different tasks. What do you mean by "*different callers*"? Depending on who calls the method, you decide what to return?

In the second case think of a more general model and return it. Then let the clients transform it to appropriate format. There are several ways to do this:

- return format-agnostic type and provide methods converting to map and to object so the client can decide. For instance if you are not sure whether the client prefers weakly-typed map with properties or strongly-typed object having the same attributes/fields, return simple wrapper having `toMap` and `toObject` methods. Note that in this case the internal representation is not important, client always uses a view and you can always add new format in the future
- return generic `Model` class having two subclasses: `MapModel` and `ObjectModel`, exposing appropriate getters in subclasses. Do **not** use `instanceof` but Visitor pattern instead. In this model you always return a single value and the client has to be able to deal with every format. If you add a new format (like `XmlModel`), all the places where `Model` is used need to be customized to deal with new type. However in this scenario you don't need to transform the internal representation to different *formats*.

Note that returning an `Object` or any variation of that is simply landing in dynamic languages land where you no longer have any static-typing help.

Comment: So for the sake of readability you **need** two methods performing different tasks. There is nothing preventing you from reusing some code internally, but the API really needs two methods to remain clean and understandable.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a strategy specific return type class that encapsulates both options to provide a clea, typed interface rather than juggling Object instanceof/casts throughout the implementing code. The tiny bit of boilerplate is acceptable in my opinion :

```
SomeClass {
    private final Map values;
    private final Object dto;

    SomeClass(Map values, Object dto) {
        ...
    }

    <D> D getDTO(Class<D> dtoType);
    Map getMap();..
}
```

Or generic the return type if you know DTO type upfront (you shouldn't, it would imply you made a poor design choice)

Answer (score 1):

create a data class with getter and setters and return the same Object..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply return an Object. Ideally, I would do that as the last option. But you can consider returning a generic as well

```
public Object myMethod1(){}

public T myMethod2(){}
```

In the second case, it is obvious you may have to define your generic object.

Answer (score 0):

What about generics?

```
public <T> T getPojo(final Object o, final Class<T> returnType)
{
    if (o instanceof HashMap)
    {
        return (T) getPojoHash((HashMap) o);
    }
    return (T) getPojoDTO((DTO) o);
}

private HashMap getPojoHash(final HashMap map)
{ // mount map
    return newMap;
}

private DTO getPojoDTO(final DTO d)
{ // mount dto
    return newDTO;
}
```

You can use reflection to avoid the `returnType` parameter. But I prefer to type.

Comment: I've updated your answer to apply the generic parameter `T` to the `Class` argument as well, making the method more type-safe and idiomatic to use.

Comment: and how would one call this method?

Comment: You just pass the hash or the dto.

Comment: So the method would have to check the type of class being passed in and build a map or dto accordingly? That's ugly. Can you please show an implementation of this method?

Comment: Either ways the implementation goes in the privates.

Comment: this won't compile. You can't pass an `Object` into either of those `private` methods.

Comment: Sorry, I was meant to give some ideas rather    than actual code that you can copy paste since I do not know enough of you requirements.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Whilst your initial idea was sound, once you delve into implementation details, you see that it is quite ugly and is not safe due to unchecked casts, so is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are returning Generic types and the list can be heterogeneous,  returning reference to an ArrayList is not a bad idea. You could encapsulate everything inside another class, but at the end of it all, you would need to maintain some kind of list somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics, but there lies a problem in your need to return both things at the same time. The best solution is to make a class that contains the two return types, and simply using generics to create a method that returns what you need:

```
public <T extends SomeReturnObject> List<T> doSomething(Object someObject, Class<T> classToReturn) {
   // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having more information on your approach, I'd try and use an interface that provides the needed methods. Then you can provide a wrapper for `HashMap`, your DTO's could implement that interface directly and you could also have a wrapper that contains a `HashMap` and a DTO.

The caller shouldn't really know what is returned as long as the needed methods are provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to put 2 methods on your Strategy interface, one for each return type.

```java
public interface Strategy {
    Map<String, String> executeReturningMap();
    DTO executeReturningDTO();
}
```

The callers can then choose for themselves which return type they want by calling the appropriate method.

No fuss, just deviating from the purist idea that a Strategy can only have one single method.